# Change colors of FuzzyFinders search pane in vim

Tags: vim

I like the functionality of the [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) plugin in vim a lot - however, the colors of the search page when using the desert color scheme is not pleasant IMHO. It is a bright purple with a black selection.

How can I change the colors of the search pane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find out which highlight groups it's using and then modify them. I believe the drop-down menu is using Pmenu and PmenuSel, so you can tweak this with:

```
:highlight Pmenu guifg=#HEXCODE guibg=#HEXCODE gui=DECORATION ctermfg=COLOR ctermbg=COLOR cterm=DECORATION
```

HEXCODE can be a hex color code and is used in gvim (or macvim or similar).

COLOR is used in console mode (where colors are supported). You can look up a list of valid colors in :help cterm-colors (but it only lists colors for 16-color terminals, there may be more).

DECORATION is a decoration style (bold, underline, undercurl, etc).

For more more information, :help highlight

Note, changing this will change the Pmenu and PmenuSel globally, so anything else in vim that uses those two highlight groups will also have their colors effected.

Comment: Great. That will certainly please my eyes soon :-)